# Como configurar um Arquivo customizado em json do Swagger no Spring boot?

Tags: web-service, api, spring, spring-boot, swagger

estou tentando configurar um arquivo json no swagger pelo spring boot, porém as vezes que eu tento ele diz que não conseguiu encontrar aquele arquivo, alguém sabe o que estou errando? Segue abaixo meus códigos:

Foto do meu projeto

[image: Foto do meu projeto]

WebConfig.java:

```
package com.restfulproject.crud;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResourcesProvider;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.restfulproject.crud.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.restfulproject.crud.*")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, DataSource dataSource) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("123456");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.restfulproject.crud.*");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean 
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket userApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .apiInfo(metaData());

    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
        return () -> {
            SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
            wsResource.setName("swagger");
            wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
            wsResource.setLocation("/api/config/swagger.json");

            List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>(defaultResourcesProvider.get());
            resources.add(wsResource);
            return resources;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/api/config/swagger.json").
                        addResourceLocations("classpath:/config/swagger.json");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/api/swagger-ui.html**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/api/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("User Crud REST API")
            .description("\"Projeto que utiliza spring boot\"")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
            .build();

      }


}
```

Pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.restfulproject.crud</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-crud</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-crud</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>user_crud</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha5 </version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adiciona essa classe no projeto:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket productApi() {

     return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
              .select()                                  
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())
              .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
              .build();  

}
}
```

Comment: Eu adicionei porém continua não achando o json file, da esta mensagem =  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/user_crud/config/swagger.json] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'